# Laravel form submission doesn't goes to the right route?

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed the latest laravel. I Have made this simple form. I want to create `post` but when I submit it goes to `localhost/post`  which is the wrong `URL` . The actual `URL` is `http://localhost/laravel_practice/`'

**Form**

```
<form method="post" action="/post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title Here">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Body</label>
    <textarea name="body" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the body"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="sumit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Publish">
</div>
```

**My Routes**

```
 Route::get('/' ,'PostController@index');

Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');
Route::post('/post','PostController@store');
```

Comment: Please check yourself question one more

Comment: Assign your route with a name, use this to get your route: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your short fix is to use `action="/laravel_practice/post"` or `action="/laravel_practice/public/post"` depending on what url you want to go.

However, it is a bad practice. You should use route name. To do that give any name to the route like below,

```
Route::post('/post','PostController@store')->name('post.store');
```

Then in view you should use,

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('post.store') }}">
```

To read more about named route you can go through this [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing).